# Using diagonalization approach, how to show the existence of at least one set of natural numbers that is not computable?

Tags: set-theory, computability, turing-machines, decidability

I have studied the halting problem and the concepts of decidability and computability, however, I am stuck with the transfer of Turing machines to sets of natural numbers. Specifically, using the diagonalization approach given a function ($f(x)$ that outputs $1$ if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0$ otherwise.

How can I demonstrate that there exists at least one set of natural numbers that is not computable?
I studied the concept of computable sets but I somehow can't make the connection from the Halting problem and diagonalization approach of it to show that a set of natural numbers is not computable.

I started setting up the table by assuming all possible sets of natural numbers on the vertical axis and an enumeration of natural numbers that represent the inputs $x$. The table will be filled with zeroes and ones depending on whether the $x$ value on the x-axis is in a given set. I then assume the existence of some sort of negator function such as $g(x) = 1 - x$. Constructing now a set of natural numbers as function of the diagonal zeroes and ones but negated, I get to the intersect and that is where I am stuck:

What does this diagonal value mean? It is supposed to represent the contradiction and hence non-computability of that particular set but how do I describe this mathematically?

Lets assume I have
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\text{set}   & 0   & 1   & 2   & 3   \\ \hline
\text{set 1} & (0) & 1   & 0   & 0   \\ \hline
\text{set 2} & 1   & (1) & 0   & 1   \\ \hline
\text{set 3} & 0   & 0   & (0) & 0   \\ \hline
\text{set-}i & 1   & 0   & 1   & (?) \\ \hline
\end{array}
Can someone please point me into the right direction, please?

Comment: Yes, the set $S$ defined by the negated diagonal is none of the sets in the table, since compared to any set-i, there is some number (i is one such number) that is in one of set-i or $S$ but not the other.

Comment: @Boxwood, that seems clear and directly follows from my example, however, how do you proceed now to the argument of contradiction? How is set-i not computable, meaning, how can f(x) on such set-i not be decided?

Comment: Does the argument go like this?: If 3 was in set-i then the negated function that defines set-i would state it is not in set-i when it is supposed to be in set-i and vice versa?